# Python Bot Downloader

Tags: bots

I want to build a telegram bot which will download dp of user but I'm not getting how to take input from user of their username ?

If they entered username then their dp should returned by the bot.
I'm using python-telegram-bot library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following endpoint.

[details are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izXEG.png)

Refer https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getuserprofilephotos for further details